# Ace.js showing content when mouse hovers or clicks marker

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

With this code I add markers to an ace instance

```
var Range = ace.require("ace/range").Range
var range = new Range(link.start.Line, link.start.Column, link.end.Line, link.end.Column);
var marker = $scope.editor.getSession().addMarker(range, "ace-related-code-highlight", "text");
```

Now I want the user to show come content when he hovers the marker or clicks it.
I can't figure out the correct api. 
May I attach an eventhandleR?

Any hints welcome

Comment: Same here. Looks like the ranges don't respond to regular DOM events which sucks.